# How to remove JWT authentication from an API?

Tags: javascript, node.js

There are some APIs in abc.js file which require authentication and there are some which do not need.

Below is an API in abc.js which do not need to be authenticated. This API is placed above the JWT authentication code.

```
router.get('/callback',function(req,res)
{
    if(req.method === "GET"){
        console.log(req.query.abc);
        console.log(req.query.abc);
        return;
    }
});
```

However, when I tried to call the API above. It returns `no access token`. Below is how I write my JWT authentication:

```
router.use(function(req, res, next) {

    // check header or url parameters or post parameters for token
    var token = req.query["access_token"] ;

    // decode token
    if (token) {

        // verifies secret and checks exp
        jwt.verify(token, process.env.SECRETKEY, function(err, decoded) {           
            if (err) {
                return res.json({ success: false, message: 'Failed to authenticate token.' });      
            } else {
                // if everything is good, save to request for use in other routes
                req.decoded = decoded;  
                next();
            }
        });

    } else {

        // if there is no token
        // return an error
        return res.status(403).send({ 
            success: false, 
            error: 'No access token.'
        });

    }

});
```

Any APIs below the code above would need to insert access token into the parameter. How can I call the `callback` API above without the need to insert access token into the parameter ? Currently, it keeps returning `no access token` when I call it.

Answer (score 1):

router.use is middleware. It will be ran before any requests processing. So previous idea won't work.

The best way is to define a no auth route :

```
router.use('/callback', function(req, res, next) {
   next()
}, function(req, res, next) {

// check header or url parameters or post parameters for token
var token = req.query["access_token"] ;

// decode token
if (token) {

    // verifies secret and checks exp
    jwt.verify(token, process.env.SECRETKEY, function(err, decoded) {           
        if (err) {
            return res.json({ success: false, message: 'Failed to authenticate token.' });      
        } else {
            // if everything is good, save to request for use in other routes
            req.decoded = decoded;  
            next();
        }
    });

} else {

    // if there is no token
    // return an error
    return res.status(403).send({ 
        success: false, 
        error: 'No access token.'
    });

}
```

});

[See express JS docs](http://expressjs.com/fr/guide/using-middleware.html)

Comment: it is still returning the same error. The If statement for callback API did not run when I put a breakpoint.

Comment: /callback?access_token={{access_token}} << this API got run instead.

Comment: I see; Router.use is a middleware processed before requests

Answer (score 0):

Use below way

```
exports.isAuthenticate = async (req, res, next) => {
  // check header or url parameters or post parameters for token
  var token = req.body.token || req.query.token || req.headers['x-access-token'];
  if (!token) {
    return sendUnauthorizedRes(res, 'Access Token not specified.');
  }
  jwt.verify(token, constants.JWTContant.SECRET_KEY, async (err, response) => {
    if (err) {
      return sendUnauthorizedRes(res, 'Invalid access token.');
    } else {
      // if everything is good, save to request for use in other routes
      req.userInfo = response;
      if (await authModel.verify(token, req.userInfo.user._id)) {
        next();
      } else {
        return sendUnauthorizedRes(res, 'Invalid access token.');
      }
    }
  });
};
```

For API with authentication

```
router.get('/api/user', jwtHandler.isAuthenticate, userController.getUserDetails);
```

For API with no authentication

```
router.post('/api/login/facebook', authController.facebookLogin);
```